# WordPress белый экран при установке

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, php7.4

Пробую установить на локалку WP 5.9.2 + nginx + php7.4-fpm

Вот конфиг:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

     root /home/rooter/Project/Sites/DoorHouse;
     index index.php;

     # log files
     access_log /var/log/nginx/door-house.access.log;
     error_log /var/log/nginx/door-house.error.log;

     client_max_body_size 100M;

     location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
     }

     location = /favicon.ico {
         log_not_found off;
         access_log off;
     }

     location = /robots.txt {
         allow all;
         log_not_found off;
         access_log off;
     }

     location ~ \.php$ {
         #include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
         fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
     }

     location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg)$ {
         expires max;
         log_not_found off;
     }

}
```

Дело в том что ошибок в логах нет, и по сути всё должно работать нормально.

У меня на localhost:80 просто белая страница.

Что я могу делать не так?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD. И в логах всё должно быть. Ты не там их смотришь или не включил логирование.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/article/nginx/

Comment: Ставьте https://localwp.com/ и не мучайтесь.